# IOS:Showing WebView through PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

in my project i am using `UIPageViewController` to show a Strip of videos on home page. for showing videos i uses `UIWebView` on `UIPageViewController`.
initially i use `UIImageView` on it and it is working fine but when i applied `UIWebView` it gives error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

please some help me to resolve this issue
i am sharing my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Create the data model
    //_pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    //_pageImages = @[@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/uObzRhWq7tk", @"Radio_Button-512.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    _videourl = @[@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/uObzRhWq7tk",@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/38DZgGjaPOA"];


    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(searchbtn.frame)+80, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/3);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

and

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count]))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.urlFile = self.videourl[index];


    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you are trying to insert nil into array. Set up a breakpoint before this line:

```
 NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
```

*startingViewController* is probably *nil*.